# QGIS: multiplying of symbology transparency

Tags: qgis, vector, export, transparency-opacity

In order to export partly transparent symbology to PDF in QGIS as vectors, the [symbology itself needs to have transparency](http://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37563#issuecomment-653518952) – if the whole layer is sat to be transparent, the symbology gets rasterized.

Having the symbology itself as transparent (which does export as vectors correctly), however, creates the effect of multiplying, increasing when elements overlap – up to a point where they no longer look transparent:

[image]

​

This is in stark contrast to having the layer itself as transparent, as below:

[image]

Unfortunately, however, this does not export as vectors. Is there a way to turn off multiplying of symbology transparency, getting the same effect as if the whole layer is transparent, in order to be able to export uniformed transparency as vectors?

Comment: From a cartographical point of view your symbology is problematic, since the symbols overlap. Can't you find a symbology which avoids this and thus also gets rid of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you export to geopdf then it won't force the layer to be rasterized as a result of layer-wide transparency or blending modes.

Comment: With this any layers with layer-wide transparency do export as vectors – but as opaque ones, losing transparency instead. Anything changed under _layer rendering_ seems to break vector exports in one way or another.

Comment: Perhaps it depends on qgis version and the PDF reader application, but it works for me!